# Why does Outlook 2010 show duplicate Tasks in the To-Do list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, email-client, tasks

I am running Outlook 2010 (64bit). Every task in my To-Do list is duplicated. If I 'complete' one task, the second copy also marks as complete. If I flag an email to be added to the task list, 2 copies are listed.

I only have a single email profile configured on the laptop. I have tried adding an addition email profile, and that seemed to resolve the problem, but only until I closed Outlook and relaunched.

Comment: **How** are you **viewing** your Tasks - via the Task List in the To Do bar?  In the To-Do List area or the Task folder itself?

Are you **syncing** your tasks with a mobile device (or anything else for that matter)?

Comment: The Tasks are not being sync with a mobile device. Everywhere within Outlook that I can view the Tasks/To-Do list they are listed twice. This include the Mail tab & the Tasks tab.

Answer (score 2):

If the duplication shows in the To-Do Bar or To-Do List but not in your Tasks folder itself, then try resetting the To-Do Bar via;

Windows XP
**Start**-> **Run**; **outlook.exe /resettodobar**
(note the space in the command

Windows Vista and Windows 7
**Start**-> type; **outlook.exe /resettodobar**
(note the space in the command)

If you see duplicates in the Tasks folder, make sure you are not seeing these duplicates because of a view settings.[See Tasks show up multiple times](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/319)

Comment: This is a Brand new install of Outlook 2010, on a fresh install of Windows 7. From the initial launch of Outlook 2010 the Items in the To-Do list are duplicated. On my 'old' laptop with Outlook 2007 installed I only see a single instance of each task. This has to be an Outlook 2010 setting.

Comment: I don't know what causes the problem, just that you have it.  Did you follow the instructions in my answer (**note:** *I just fixed some formatting, if it didn't work, it should now*).

Comment: Yes sir, I followed your commands, and read/followed the suggestions on the site the you listed. Problem continues. Is it possible that Outlook2010 is reading data from both the Server & a local copy of data?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth checking to see if your auto-archive is causing the duplication, check within your Tasks to see if you have Tasks duplicated (should see a different Task list for each .PST)

You would also get it if you had imported an old PST into your current and then selected to open the old PST as a seperate folder file, effectively duplicating your data.

Comment: It took a lot of searching to find this, which solved my issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Outlook with GMail over IMAP? If so then it's because Gmail’s IMAP shows the same item in multiple folders. This causes the tasks in your To-Do bar to be shown more than once.

You can fix the problem using the instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/prevent-outlook-with-gmail-imap-from-showing-duplicate-tasks-in-the-to-do-bar/).

Answer (score 0):

The real root cause is that the AutoArchive to Tasks and you added the archive *.pst in DataFile.

Solution:
(1) Remove AutoArchive to all Task list.
(2) Remove the previous archive *.pst from Data Files.

Answer (score 0):

solved...!!!
I found that Google creates other folders such as 'starred' that keeps a copy of the emails that have been flagged. Since outlook keeps a copy of the email in both the 'inbox' and 'starred' folders, when you flag the email it flags both copies and you end up with 2 flagged copies in the task pane.

I had to go to my gmail account on the web browser, find the 'starred' and then select 'hide'. Once you hide the 'starred' folder you refresh your outlook app and the 'starred' folders disappears and so does the duplicate tagged email.

This was so frustrating, glad I found it and could share to the rest of you.